# .NET WinApp wont run on other machine depending of compile machine

Tags: .net, windows, copy, compilation

Ok I am missing something here.

I have my dev computer (x86, windows 7) with visual studio Premium.
I have a test machine (x86, windows XP) with visual studio express.

On both compute I compile the exact same thing (winapp + few dll project) in same .net version (3.5) and all the external references are found and accessible in both cases also both machines are on the same domain.

On my test, when I compile, it works and it runs on both when copying and opening app
On my dev, it works, and run on itself but when I copy output to test, it wont open.

I have double checked and tried all the build config and it is always the same result (debug/release, any-cpu/x86, etc)

I also tried to put my code in try catch and add a handler on appdomain unhandled exception and it is always the same error...

I have googled the error tried a bunch of things but I am running out of ideas.
A clue on where or what to search for would be greatly apprceciated!

Here's the error :

```
Type de l'événement : Erreur  
Source de l'événement : .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting  
Catégorie de l'événement : Aucun  
ID de l'événement : 5000  
Date :  24-11-2010  
Heure :  09:17:09  
Utilisateur : N/A  
Ordinateur : PCD25569  
Description : EventType clr20r3, P1 waf_detours.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4ced1e3e, P4 waf_detours, P5 1.0.0.0, P6 4ced1e3e, P7 d, P8 c6, P9 system.invalidoperationexception, P10 NIL.

Pour plus d'informations, consultez le centre Aide et support à l'adresse http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Données :
0000: 63 00 6c 00 72 00 32 00   c.l.r.2.
0008: 30 00 72 00 33 00 2c 00   0.r.3.,.
0010: 20 00 77 00 61 00 66 00    .w.a.f.
0018: 5f 00 64 00 65 00 74 00   _.d.e.t.
0020: 6f 00 75 00 72 00 73 00   o.u.r.s.
0028: 2e 00 65 00 78 00 65 00   ..e.x.e.
0030: 2c 00 20 00 31 00 2e 00   ,. .1...
0038: 30 00 2e 00 30 00 2e 00   0...0...
0040: 30 00 2c 00 20 00 34 00   0.,. .4.
0048: 63 00 65 00 64 00 31 00   c.e.d.1.
0050: 65 00 33 00 65 00 2c 00   e.3.e.,.
0058: 20 00 77 00 61 00 66 00    .w.a.f.
0060: 5f 00 64 00 65 00 74 00   _.d.e.t.
0068: 6f 00 75 00 72 00 73 00   o.u.r.s.
0070: 2c 00 20 00 31 00 2e 00   ,. .1...
0078: 30 00 2e 00 30 00 2e 00   0...0...
0080: 30 00 2c 00 20 00 34 00   0.,. .4.
0088: 63 00 65 00 64 00 31 00   c.e.d.1.
0090: 65 00 33 00 65 00 2c 00   e.3.e.,.
0098: 20 00 64 00 2c 00 20 00    .d.,. .
00a0: 63 00 36 00 2c 00 20 00   c.6.,. .
00a8: 73 00 79 00 73 00 74 00   s.y.s.t.
00b0: 65 00 6d 00 2e 00 69 00   e.m...i.
00b8: 6e 00 76 00 61 00 6c 00   n.v.a.l.
00c0: 69 00 64 00 6f 00 70 00   i.d.o.p.
00c8: 65 00 72 00 61 00 74 00   e.r.a.t.
00d0: 69 00 6f 00 6e 00 65 00   i.o.n.e.
00d8: 78 00 63 00 65 00 70 00   x.c.e.p.
00e0: 74 00 69 00 6f 00 6e 00   t.i.o.n.
00e8: 20 00 4e 00 49 00 4c 00    .N.I.L.
00f0: 0d 00 0a 00               ....
```

Comment: Looks like `system.invalidoperationexception`

Comment: In your AppDomain exception handler, extract the message and stacktrace values and update your question with those. The `InvalidOperationException` isn't much worth without any pointer to what the error message is and where it occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, by looking at the difference in the output of the 2 compiled project, one external reference of a sub project (dll) was missing. I have no clue why it was missing but by copying it to the output directory it solved all my problem. It always seem like we need to post for help in order to find the answer....